# Regex no Web Scenario do Zabbix 4.2

Tags: regex, zabbix, monitoramento

Como recuperar valores com regex do retorno de um web scenario no Zabbix que chama uma API. O Web Scenario é para testes de paginas web e APIs no Zabbix.

Eu já tenho a expressão regular que recupera o valor e segundo a documentação do Zabbix, preciso apenas passar a expressão dessa maneira: regex:\w{54} [documentação](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/web_monitoring), porém ele não recupera o response, ele não entende a expressão. Abaixo a configuração do step:

Erro:

```
Error: error in step variables "{access_token}=regex:[A-Za-z0-9]{54} {be}=Bearer ": cannot extract the value of "{access_token}" from response
```

Retorno da API, da qual eu preciso recuperar o access_token:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: PRINT-CONFIGURAÇÃO-SCENARIO]

Comment: posta a parte do código referente ao erro. Assim fica mais fácil de entenderem e te ajudarem

Comment: então, não tem código em si, é td configurado no Zabbix, eu adicionei o response da API, talvez seja isso que vc quiz dizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de analisar bem a documentação e achar um exemplo bem escroto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E descobrir q não é igual esse exemplo, rs. De qualquer forma isso me ajudou, repare que após o `content="(..` tem esse parênteses e foi ai que fiz o teste e deu certo, mas olha como ficou o resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha regra de expressão é: `\w{54}` e eu testei conforme manda a documentação abaixo, que devia ser assim: `regex:access_token is (\w{54})`, mas isso não funciona, pelo menos para o meu caso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumo: Use a regex dessa maneira: `regex:"(\w{54})"` lembrando que estamos falando do Web Scenario do Zabbix e sua expressão regular deve ficar dentro dos parênteses.